# Matrix derivative in multiple linear regression model

Tags: matrices, statistics, linear-regression

The basic setup in multiple linear regression model is

\begin{align}
    Y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           y_{1} \\
           y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           y_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    X &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 & x_{11} & \dots & x_{1k}\\
           1 &x_{21} & \dots & x_{2k}\\
           \vdots & \dots & \dots\\
           1 & x_{n1} & \dots & x_{nk}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    \beta &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \beta_{0} \\
           \beta_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           \beta_{k}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    \epsilon &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \epsilon_{1} \\
           \epsilon_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           \epsilon_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

The regression model is $Y=X \beta + \epsilon$.

To find least square estimator of $\beta$ vector, we need to minimize $S(\beta)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i^2 = \epsilon ' \epsilon = (y-x\beta)'(y-x\beta)=y'y-2\beta 'x'y + \beta 'x'x \beta$

$$\frac{\partial S(\beta)}{\partial \beta}=0$$

My question: how to get $-2x'y+2x'x \beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the squared errors can be written as

$$
  \left\lVert \epsilon \right\rVert^2 = \left\lVert Y - X\beta \right
\rVert^2
$$
$$
  = (Y - X\beta)^T(Y - X\beta) = Y^TY - \beta^TX^TY - Y^TX\beta + \beta^TX^TX\beta
$$
$$
  = \left\lVert Y \right\rVert^2 - 2Y^TX\beta + \left\lVert X\beta \right\rVert^2
$$

Then, finding the gradient $\frac{d\left\lVert \epsilon \right\rVert^2}{d\beta}$

$$
  \frac{d\left\lVert \epsilon \right\rVert^2}{d\beta} = -2X^TY + 2X^TX\beta
$$

Reviewing term by term in that differentiation (since differentiation is linear operator!)

$\left\lVert Y \right\rVert^2$ does not depend on $\beta$ and becomes $0$.

$2Y^TX\beta$ is a is a sum where the $i^{th}$ term is $2\beta_iY^Tx_i$ where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $X$. Therefore, the gradient of this term evaluates to $-2X^TY$.

$\left\lVert X\beta \right\rVert^2$ can be [differentiated using the product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296697/differentiation-of-vector-norms)

In general, the [Jacobian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680708/what-is-the-difference-between-the-jacobian-hessian-and-the-gradient) of $f(x) = Ax $ is $ J_f =  A^T$

Comment: Your last sentence is very helpful. But how to apply the rule in $\beta 'x'x \beta$?

Comment: I find this source is more helpful: http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/teaching/courses/sntn/sntn-2017/resources/Matrix_derivatives_cribsheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\b{\beta}\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\l{\lambda}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Instead of expanding $\,\e\,$ **before** differentiating, do the differentiation first.
$$\eqalign{
\e &= X\b-Y \\
\l &= \e^T\e \\
d\l &= 2\e^T\c{d\e} = 2\e^T\CLR{X\,d\b} = \LR{2X^T\e}^Td\b \\
\grad{\l}{\b} &= 2X^T\c{\e} = 2X^T\CLR{X\b-Y} \\
}$$
To find the minimizer, set this gradient to zero and solve for $\b$.
$$\eqalign{
X^TX\b &= X^TY \\
\b &= \c{\LR{X^TX}^{-1}X^T}Y \;=\; \c{X^+}Y \\
}$$
where $X^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $X$.